# Access filtered data after the filtering in React

Tags: reactjs

There is a post and this post has an array of objects called wasteItemList. I try to get the data of this one object in the array. To do this I use a filter and this gives me correct data. This is how I try it.

```
const wasteItems = posts && posts.wasteItemList && posts.wasteItemList.filter(wasteItem => wasteItem._id===arrayId);
console.log(wasteItems);
```

This is the data that I got from filtering.

[image: Results of the filtering]

I want to access the data inside the `wasteItems`. So to do that I tried like this `console.log(wasteItems._id);` but I got an error says 'TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined'. How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. You should use `find` instead `filter` to find an element. It will return an element instead of an array.

```
const wasteItem = posts?.wasteItemList?.find(wasteItem => wasteItem._id===arrayId);
```

Second. The result after search may be `undefined`. So you need to check it after using:

```
console.log(wasteItems?._id)
```

Comment: It works for me and I understand what the error was. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Array.filter returns an array, so when you say `wasteItems._id` it can't access that like an object.

If you are only looking for that specific wasteItem, do this:

```
const wasteItem = posts && posts.wasteItemLis.find(wasteItem => wasteItem._id=== arrayId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Array.filter returns the data in array format. To access the data either you should use map/forEach on the returned data or if filter data always contains one element then instead of using Array.filter use Array.find.

Solution 1 -

```
const wasteItems = posts && posts.wasteItemList && posts.wasteItemList.filter(wasteItem => wasteItem._id===arrayId);
wasteItems.forEach(wasteItem=>{console.log(wasteItem._id)})
```

Solution 2 -

```
const wasteItems = posts && posts.wasteItemList && posts.wasteItemList.find(wasteItem => wasteItem._id===arrayId);
console.log(wasteItems._id);
```